# How to store checklist from php using x-editable

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Good day! I was still figuring out how can I show the select list from the database. But it always print the word "Array". I want to store

html

```
 html_data += '<td data-name="first_name" class="first_name" data-
 type="checklist" data-
 pk="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].first_name+'</td>';
```

js

```
 $('#employee_data').editable({
  container: 'body',
  selector: 'td.first_name',
  url: "update.php",
  title: 'Employee Name',
        value: [2, 3],    
        source: [
              {value: 1, text: 'option1'},
              {value: 2, text: 'option2'},
              {value: 3, text: 'option3'}
           ],
  type: "POST",
  //dataType: 'json',
  validate: function(value){
   if($.trim(value) == '')
   {
    return 'This field is required';
   }
  }
 });
```

fetch php

```
<?php
//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
$query = "SELECT * FROM user";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$output = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 $output[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

update.php

```
<?php
//update.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
$query = "
 UPDATE user SET ".$_POST["name"]." = '".$_POST["value"]."' 
 WHERE id = '".$_POST["pk"]."'";
mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>
```

The output should be "option2" and "option3" but unfortunately it keep showing the word "Array". Can you please help me where i

Comment: I tried to include array() under javascript code but it is not working

Comment: $('#employee_data').editable({
  container: 'body',
  selector: 'td.first_name',
  url: "update.php",
  title: 'Employee Name',
        value: array(),    
        source: [
              {value: 1, text: 'option1'},
              {value: 2, text: 'option2'},
              {value: 3, text: 'option3'}
           ],
  type: "POST",
  //dataType: 'json',
  validate: function(value){
   if($.trim(value) == '')
   {
    return 'This field is required';
   }
  }
 });

Comment: It seems that it is not storing on my database and the default is "Array"